# Handling file uploads in PHP

Tags: php, web-applications, upload

TLDR; How do I reference a temp file upload POSTed to a PHP script from within the PHP script?

I'm working on creating a web app (just for lab testing, doesn't need much security) that allows me to upload and aggregate XML&XLS files.

I've got everything worked out except for how to work with the file itself after the user POSTs it to the server using an HTML form.

I have a form that POSTs the file to the server, and I have a PHP script that is set up to do something with the file, but I'm falling short on understanding how to reference the uploaded file from the PHP script on the server.

EG:

`<form action="Update_data.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"></br>
    <INPUT type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></br>
</form>`

and I'm vaguely aware that when the file is posted the file exists in a temp directory on the server until Update_data.php finishes executing. That's all fine and well, but I don't know what that directory would be, or even if I need to configure PHP.ini in some specific way to allow this.

So, what I'm asking is:

How do I reference a temp file upload POSTed to a PHP script from within the PHP script?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php?

Comment: I did read that but I did not understand how I can pass the file as data to a function from the information there. If I can simply use the file name, then it is more rudimentary than I expected, but I wasn't certain in my reasoning that the file exists in a temporary directory until the script finishes executing or not. Perhaps the TLDR was too much of a summary.

Comment: No; I've read much of it myself - I'm sorry that this question was too simple for you. Perhaps you should try harder ones. I've noticed that quite a few of your responses on this website are extremely sarcastic and mildly insulting, even when helpful. If you're going to behave that way, why not just opt to remain silent? I think it's apparent from the difficulty that I'm having that I either did not understand the manual, or I did not notice the segment that addresses the problem I am having. I am sure you have overlooked things before.

Comment: @eicto, lmgtfy is *never* appropriate.  If you're going to issue an RTFM, then at least point at the actual manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` contains the file name of the uploaded file on the server.

Yu can use the `move_uploaded_file()` function to move the uploaded file to whatever location you need.

This manual page contains all the information you need: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Yes I read that from the manual, but as I said I wasn't sure if the file was temporary or not, or what directory it exists in temporarily...

Comment: `move_uploaded_file` will remove the file from the tmp location. Where that file is is dependant on your PHP configucation: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir

Comment: Oh ok thank you that's what I needed - the part I was really uncertain about was how I could possibly determine the full path of the file when I did not know what directory it was created in..thank you very much.